# Непонятное поведение Get запроса

Tags: jquery, javascript

Стала часто появляться ошибка. Примерно 1 раз за 10-15-20 минут:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Если перейти через адресную строку по ссылке, то всё ОК. Есть предположение, что сервер не может обработать долгий запрос. Что в таком случае делать?

Сам GET запрос отсылается так:

```
 function get_test() {
  $.get('/online_bot/run', {
   social_type: social_type,
   tasks_type: checks.getValueCheckbox(types_elem),
   captcha_sid: $('#vk_captcha_sid').val(),
   captcha_key: $('#vk_captcha_code').val()
  }, function(data) {
   get_test();
  });
 }
```

[image]

Comment: нужно смотреть в  логи сервера, чтобы понять, что там. 500 ошибка это ошибка на стороне серверных скриптов.

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить время выполнения php-скриптов в php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае нужно профилировать код, начать писать в лог время исполнения, потом детализировать логи, замеряя разные участки кода. Если идет работа с базой, то у них всегда можно включить логирование тормозных запросов. Так же есть вероятность, что обработка обыного `GET` отличается от Ajax (см в коде на проверку хедера `X-Requested-With`).